# pandas cut into intervals hyper-parameters

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

I am trying to match several data frames on one interval column which is a result of a pd.cut() function.
However, the matching doesn`t work due to the fact that the pd.cut() produces different outcomes.

For example:
While cutting a float numbers series into bins of [15, 16, 17, 18], the pd.cut function produces sometimes the following intervals - **option A:**

(15, 16], (16, 17], (17, 18]

and sometimes it produces with the following intervals -  **option B:**

(15.0, 16.0], (16.0, 17.0], (17.0, 18.0]

Change of hyper-parameters such as precision don`t help. 
And the funny thing is that for option B result when you group-by the intervals, the grouped names are actually as option A - (15, 16], (16, 17], (17, 18]

Which hyper parameters should I use for the pd.cut() function?

Comment: Guessing that it has to do with the datatype of the concerned columns. Have you tried converting the columns that give option A to floats before cutting them? Also, on a side note: I don't see anything wrong with adding labels to the `pd.cut()` and using those to match

Comment: in option A they are float already.

Comment: I'm lost for explanations then. What's the reason why you don't want to use labels?

Comment: Used labels. I just don`t understand why the default is random and uncontrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Yup it works, a possible solution is just manually adding labels for the pd.cut() intervals as legend.

```
df['a_groups'] = pd.qcut(df.a, q=3, labels=['(15, 16]', '(16, 17]', '(17, 18]'])
```